# Import doesn´t generate System.register as expect

Tags: typescript, angular

I´m newbie with Angular2, I´m learning and I´m doing an excercise to practice. I´m following a course from Udemy and I´m comparing my excercise with this one.

I have my app.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ClienteListaComponent} from './components/cliente-lista.component';
import {ClienteDetalleComponent} from './components/cliente-detalle.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: 'app/views/clientes.html',
})

export class AppComponent{

}
```

Obviously that is my bootstrap defined in main.ts

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Code in "app" selector works fine. The problem is when I try to use selectors defined in "ClienteListaComponent" or "ClienteDetalleComponent".

I think the problem is generating app.component.js .. system.register only have angular2/core and not the other imports.

```
System.register(['angular2/core'], function(exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
        var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
        if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
        else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
        return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
    };
    var __metadata = (this && this.__metadata) || function (k, v) {
        if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.metadata === "function") return Reflect.metadata(k, v);
    };
    var core_1;
    var AppComponent;
    return {
        setters:[
            function (core_1_1) {
                core_1 = core_1_1;
            }],
        execute: function() {
            AppComponent = (function () {
                function AppComponent() {
                }
                AppComponent = __decorate([
                    core_1.Component({
                        selector: 'app',
                        templateUrl: 'app/views/clientes.html',
                    }), 
                    __metadata('design:paramtypes', [])
                ], AppComponent);
                return AppComponent;
            }());
            exports_1("AppComponent", AppComponent);
        }
    }
});
```

.. therefore I can use "ClienteListaComponent" and ClienteDetalleComponent".

I´m using angular 2.0.0-beta.14 because the course I´m following use this.

I´m driving myself insane, I hope anybody can help me. Thanks ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.. I´m the problem jejeje.. I did´t load the directives inside component decorator.
I wrote:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: 'app/views/clientes.html',
})
```

and should be

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: 'app/views/clientes.html',
  directives:[
            PeliculasListComponent, 
            PeliculasFooterComponent
  ] 
})
```